# How can I change my system colors to default?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

In my C++ application I wrongly changed system color:

```
const INT val = COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT;
  const COLORREF color = RGB(255,0,0);
  ::SetSysColors(1, &val, &color);
```

How can I restore backwards default settings?

Comment: Don't reinstall Windows just yet.  First try logging out and logging back in.

Comment: Ok, I am on my way to log out.

Comment: @ Hans Passant thank you very much, I should try to reboot before begin to panic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation on SetSysColors() at  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724940%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
says "The new colors are not saved when the system terminates." so rebooting will probably get your colours back.

There is an example of how to get a copy of the colors with GetSysColors() before changing them with SetSysColors(), and it then shows how to restore the colors.